# Access desktop remotely via web browser?

Tags: web-apps, remote-access

I'm trying to find an app which lets you remotely access your computer in a web browser. I've done some research about and I didn't find much.

Do you know a good web app/service that could do this?

EDIT: By *web app* I mean a tool, such as a Flash application, not just a regular remote desktop program.

Comment: [VNC can be used in a web browser.](https://www.google.nl/search?q=vnc%20browser)

Comment: Chrome remote desktop is a Google Chrome application and can be used to control remote computer just like TeamViewer. You also have an android app which can be used to control from mobile itself. You and the other party needs to have google chrome installed. Try it and let me know if that fits ur requirements. If it's fine, I will write this as another answer.

Comment: My problem is, I need to remotely access it from school - I've used Chrome Remote Desktop before, but extensions/apps are blocked at school.

Comment: @reinierpost write that as an answer

Comment: I did, and it was converted to a comment :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[noVNC](http://novnc.com/info.html) is probably your best bet for this.  It's pretty widely used by a lot of smaller cloud providers for console access to hosted systems, and the project itself actually hosts a standalone version on their site.  There are a couple of other options for VNC usage from a browser, but from what I've seen noVNC is the lightest and simplest to use.

There's also [FreeRDB-WebConnect](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP-WebConnect), which is a bit more involved to set up, but requires no additional software on the system you want to connect to if it's a Windows computer.

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting your request for "an app" to mean an application and not a program operating on a mobile device.

You have not specified the requirement of a free program. One can use TeamViewer within a web browser to access a remote computer. It requires that the computer being controlled to have the application operating either by starting manually, or started automatically from within the settings.

It's not what I would call inexpensive, especially now that they have gone to a subscription basis.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit vague. When I said "web app" I meant a tool or something that needs no installation, and is served over a web browser, not a program.